How to sort the terms in a polynomial according to their degree?
I have the polynomial
(224 p^2)/9+(224 p^3)/45+(11 p^4)/45-(352 p q)/9-(128 p^2 q)/45+(2 p^3 q)/45+(224 q^2)/9-(128 p q^2)/45-(23 p^2 q^2)/45+(224 q^3)/45+(2 p q^3)/45+(11 q^4)/45+(128 p r)/9+(352 p^2 r)/45+(32 p^3 r)/45-(352 q r)/9-(64 p q r)/5+2/45 p^2 q r-(128 q^2 r)/45-58/45 p q^2 r+(2 q^3 r)/45+(224 r^2)/9+(352 p r^2)/45+(22 p^2 r^2)/45-(128 q r^2)/45+2/45 p q r^2-(23 q^2 r^2)/45+(224 r^3)/45+(32 p r^3)/45+(2 q r^3)/45+(11 r^4)/45+(128 p s)/9+(352 p^2 s)/45+(32 p^3 s)/45+(128 q s)/9-(32 p q s)/15+32/45 p^2 q s+(352 q^2 s)/45+32/45 p q^2 s+(32 q^3 s)/45-(352 r s)/9-(32 p r s)/15+2/45 p^2 r s-(64 q r s)/5-2 p q r s+2/45 q^2 r s-(128 r^2 s)/45+32/45 p r^2 s-58/45 q r^2 s+(2 r^3 s)/45+(224 s^2)/9+(352 p s^2)/45+(22 p^2 s^2)/45+(352 q s^2)/45+2/45 p q s^2+(22 q^2 s^2)/45-(128 r s^2)/45+32/45 p r s^2+2/45 q r s^2-(23 r^2 s^2)/45+(224 s^3)/45+(32 p s^3)/45+(32 q s^3)/45+(2 r s^3)/45+(11 s^4)/45

and I need to sort its terms according to their degree.
For example, $\frac{32 p^3 s}{45}$ has degree $4$, and $-\frac{1}{9} (352 p q)$ has degree $2$.
How to do this?

Do you want this for manipulations or simply to look at the terms?

@bmf I need this for further manipulations.

I suggest that you break the term in a list and you take it from there. Plus is orderless and if you use TraditionalForm it's a wrapper; like the MatrixForm if you are familiar with that. Not sure how happy you are with making a list of the terms

That is okay, but I don't want the signs to be changed, like $-\frac19(352pq)$ should remain negative in the list. @bmf

Does MonomialList[poly, "DegreeLexicographic"] do the trick?

Definitely a task for MonomialList (as @march suggested already(.

Since there is a good reason for Mathematica to have the standard monomial ordering, I advise you to work with an alternative way, say using lists.
The following function gives a list of coefficients each (total) degree:
mycoefflist[poly_] := 
  Module[{dummy, vars, rep}, vars = Variables[poly];
   rep = (# -> #*dummy) & /@ vars;
   CoefficientList[poly /. rep, dummy]];

For example,
 poly=(224 p^2)/9+(224 p^3)/45+(11 p^4)/45-(352 p q)/9-(128 p^2 q)/45+(2 p^3 q)/45+(224 q^2)/9-(128 p q^2)/45-(23 p^2 q^2)/45+(224 q^3)/45+(2 p q^3)/45+(11 q^4)/45+(128 p r)/9+(352 p^2 r)/45+(32 p^3 r)/45-(352 q r)/9-(64 p q r)/5+2/45 p^2 q r-(128 q^2 r)/45-58/45 p q^2 r+(2 q^3 r)/45+(224 r^2)/9+(352 p r^2)/45+(22 p^2 r^2)/45-(128 q r^2)/45+2/45 p q r^2-(23 q^2 r^2)/45+(224 r^3)/45+(32 p r^3)/45+(2 q r^3)/45+(11 r^4)/45+(128 p s)/9+(352 p^2 s)/45+(32 p^3 s)/45+(128 q s)/9-(32 p q s)/15+32/45 p^2 q s+(352 q^2 s)/45+32/45 p q^2 s+(32 q^3 s)/45-(352 r s)/9-(32 p r s)/15+2/45 p^2 r s-(64 q r s)/5-2 p q r s+2/45 q^2 r s-(128 r^2 s)/45+32/45 p r^2 s-58/45 q r^2 s+(2 r^3 s)/45+(224 s^2)/9+(352 p s^2)/45+(22 p^2 s^2)/45+(352 q s^2)/45+2/45 p q s^2+(22 q^2 s^2)/45-(128 r s^2)/45+32/45 p r s^2+2/45 q r s^2-(23 r^2 s^2)/45+(224 s^3)/45+(32 p s^3)/45+(32 q s^3)/45+(2 r s^3)/45+(11 s^4)/45;

 clist = mycoefflist[poly]

gives

and you can recover the original polynomial simply by taking Total[] of the list. Thus
 Total[clist]===poly
 (* True *) 


I believe that what you want is built in:
MonomialList[poly, "DegreeLexicographic"]

sorts the terms by degree from largest to smallest, and lexicographically within each degree. If you want the degree to increase instead, you can do
MonomialList[poly, "NegativeDegreeLexicographic"]

This makes a list of the monomials.  If you want to display it as a summation, there are a lot of things you can do.  One way is to do
HoldForm[CirclePlus @@ MonomialList[poly, "DegreeLexicographic"] // Evaluate] /. CirclePlus -> Plus


If I understand, you want to only sort on powers of p and s and nothing else? i.e. the q and r are not taken into account?
In this case you could try
poly = (224  p^2)/9 + (224  p^3)/45 + (11  p^4)/45 - (352  p  q)/
    9 - (128  p^2  q)/45 + (2  p^3  q)/45 + (224  q^2)/
    9 - (128  p  q^2)/45 - (23  p^2  q^2)/45 + (224  q^3)/
    45 + (2  p  q^3)/45 + (11  q^4)/45 + (128  p  r)/
    9 + (352  p^2  r)/45 + (32  p^3  r)/45 - (352  q  r)/
    9 - (64  p  q  r)/5 + 2/45  p^2  q  r - (128  q^2  r)/45 - 
   58/45  p  q^2  r + (2  q^3  r)/45 + (224  r^2)/9 + (352  p  r^2)/
    45 + (22  p^2  r^2)/45 - (128  q  r^2)/45 + 
   2/45  p  q  r^2 - (23  q^2  r^2)/45 + (224  r^3)/45 + (32  p  r^3)/
    45 + (2  q  r^3)/45 + (11  r^4)/45 + (128  p  s)/
    9 + (352  p^2  s)/45 + (32  p^3  s)/45 + (128  q  s)/
    9 - (32  p  q  s)/15 + 32/45  p^2  q  s + (352  q^2  s)/45 + 
   32/45  p  q^2  s + (32  q^3  s)/45 - (352  r  s)/9 - (32  p  r  s)/
    15 + 2/45  p^2  r  s - (64  q  r  s)/5 - 2  p  q  r  s + 
   2/45  q^2  r  s - (128  r^2  s)/45 + 32/45  p  r^2  s - 
   58/45  q  r^2  s + (2  r^3  s)/45 + (224  s^2)/9 + (352  p  s^2)/
    45 + (22  p^2  s^2)/45 + (352  q  s^2)/45 + 
   2/45  p  q  s^2 + (22  q^2  s^2)/45 - (128  r  s^2)/45 + 
   32/45  p  r  s^2 + 
   2/45  q  r  s^2 - (23  r^2  s^2)/45 + (224  s^3)/45 + (32  p  s^3)/
    45 + (32  q  s^3)/45 + (2  r  s^3)/45 + (11  s^4)/45;

And now
coef = CoefficientRules[poly, {p, s}];
coef = Reverse@SortBy[coef, Total[#[[1]]] &];
ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]
newp = ((#[[2]]*(HoldForm[p]^#[[1, 1]]*HoldForm[s]^#[[1, 2]])) & /@ coef);
Plus @@ newp

Gives

This is sorted by total powers of p and s. The first terms has 4 powers, then 3 and so on.
If you want to account for all variables. this can also be changed to do that. It was not clear to me which variables you wanted to use.
If you want all variables, then do
coef = CoefficientRules[poly, {p, s, r, q}];
coef = Reverse@SortBy[coef, Total[#[[1]]] &];
ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]
newp = ((#[[2]]*(HoldForm[p]^#[[1, 1]]*HoldForm[s]^#[[1, 2]]*
         HoldForm[r]^#[[1, 3]]*HoldForm[q]^#[[1, 4]])) & /@ coef);
Plus @@ newp

Gives

Note that once you release the Hold and rest Plus back to be orderless, you will lose the structure above. So the above is basically for display only really since Mathematica Frontend has its own rule for displaying things.
